# Trying to create procedure to fill MySql field with age

Tags: mysql

I have a field with a person's DOB entered and an empty field for the age. I am trying to set a procedure that will automatically enter the age in based on the DOB field. The below procedure will compile but it won't execute (I get SQL Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s)). Any ideas, hints, comments, etc. ?

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' PROCEDURE age_create ()
BEGIN
   update rt_referrals
   Set rt_age=
   (SELECT rt_dob, CURDATE(),
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,rt_dob,CURDATE()))
    ;
END|

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your `SELECT` query returns 3 columns whereas `SET` only expects 1, try with the below `SELECT`:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,rt_dob,CURDATE());
```